# Modelling constraints in Choco solver

Tags: java, constraint-programming, choco

I'm playing around with choco solver to solve some task scheduling problems.

I have several jobs and possible slots (where a job can be executed).
There are some constraints like:

- There could only one job per slot (C.1)
- A job needs a certain time `t` and slot has an available duration `d`. 
  The job must fit into the that available duration: `t<=d` (C.2)

So, basically expressed with some basic/pseudo classes:

```
class Job {
    int id;
    int time;
}

class Slot {
    int id;
    int duration;
}
```

Currently, I'm able to allocate a slot for each job, assuming that id of a job and a slot are consecutively numbered

```
int jobCount = 5;  // 5 jobs with ids from 0 to 4
int slotCount= 20; // 20 jobs with ids from 0 to 19
Model model = new Model("Example");
IntVar[] jobs = model.intVarArray("Job", jobCount, 0, slotCount, false);
// all jobs must have different slots (C.1)
model.allDifferent(jobs).post();

// solving - details omitted, because I think it is not relevant...
Solution solution = model.getSolver().findSolution();
// assign the jobs to the slots like (pseudo-code): 
// foreach i in jobs.length do 
//     job = getJobForId(i);
//     getSlotForId(jobs[i]).setJob(job);
```

This is working as expected. But now I want to model the other constraints as well. But I'm stucking on how to combine the job/slot with the times/durations, because the time and duration is a dependent variable.

At a first step, I modeled two additional variables for times and durations:

```
int[] slotDurations = {10, 20, 10, 40, ..., 20} // 20 durations (d)
IntVar[] durations = model.intVarArray("Time", slotCount, slotDurations);

int[] jobTimes = {5, 16, 30, 2, 17} // 5 times (t)
IntVar[] times = model.intVarArray("Time", jobCount , jobTimes);
```

Now, I need to express the constraint that the time should fit into the duration (C.2).

Is it possible to define a constraint like this (not working/valid pseudo-code):

```
for(int i=0;i<jobCount;i++){
    times[i].le(durations[jobs[i]]).post();
}
```

or is the model totally wrong?!

Maybe someone has a solution or an idea?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you say that there can be only one job per slot, then it is natural to select `slot` as your `IntVarArray`, as so:

```
 IntVar[] slots = model.intVarArray("Slot", slotCount, 0, jobCount, false);
 int[] jobTimes = {0, 5, 16, 30, 2, 17};  //6(!) items; see explanation below.
 int[] slotDurations = {10, 20, 10, 40, ..., 20}; //20 items
```

Here, `slots` points to the items in `jobTime`. If you have more slots than jobs, then take care with the `allDifferent` constraint: You will end up having no solutions. In that case, use a modified constraint, such as `allDifferentExcept0` so that the solver can select a valid item. Then, `jobTimes[0]` must be an entry satisfying all slots (say, 0).

Then you are very close. All you need to do is to introduce an intermediate `IntVar`variable, say `shadowTime`, which represents the times in the order given by  `slots`, like so:

```
IntVar[] shadowTime = model.intVarArray("shadowTime", slotDurations.length, 0, jobTimes.length, false); //has the jobTimes in the order indicated by slots.
for(int i=0;i<slotCount;i++){
    model.element(shadowTime[i], jobTimes, slots[i]).post();
    //this is similar to what you wanted to achieve with 'durations[jobs[i]]' in your code
}
```

Then you can add the constraint C.2 in the same loop:

```
//within in the above loop:
{    
    ...
    model.arithm(shadowTime[i], "<", slotDurations[i]).post();
}
```

You can then enumerate all solutions as described in the manual (`while (solver.solver(){...}`).

Comment: The `model.element` helped me! There could be hundreds of slots but only a few jobs, so I more or less just added that `shadow` and the constraint similar to your second part. Thanks!